# Append Laravel model namespace as table prefix

Tags: php, laravel, model, laravel-artisan

I am working on a Laravel 5.5 project that contains multiple "applications": Articles, Notes, Photos, etc.

Each application should have its own directory/namespace, containing its models:

```
app/
    Blog/
        Article.php
        Category.php
    Notes/
        Note.php
        Category.php
    ...
```

When I run this command  `php artisan make:model --migration Blog/Category`, it successfully creates a `app/Blog/Category.php` model and `App\Blog` namespace, but the associated migration creates a table named `category`, instead of `blog_category`. Which is problematic since I also need to create `app/Notes/Category.php`.

Is there a trick to prefix `category` tables ? Would Laravel resolves those tables if I manually change their names, or must I add a `$table` attribute in each model?

Isn't it surprising that Model namespace and table name are not related by prefix, following Laravel logic?

Comment: You can actually create your own migrations if that's easier, `php artisan make:migration create_blog_category_table` for example. Also sidenote, would there be any difference between records inserted into `blog_category` and `note_category`, aside from the parent model?

Answer (score 2):

There is two choice to solve it:

- Make the model with BlogArticle which will create blog_articles table
- OR add `$table="your table name"` to every model

Answer (score 1):

this trait can help you

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

trait TableNameResolver
{
    public $base_namespace=__NAMESPACE__;

    public function getTable()
    {
        if (! isset($this->table)) {
           $this->setTable(str_replace(
                '\\', '', Str::snake(Str::plural(trim(str_after(get_class($this),trim($this->base_namespace,'\\')),'\\')))
            ));
        }
        return $this->table;
    }
}
```

Comment: Been searching for this. I have done some changes to make it more prominent.  Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer for the_hasanov:

I have done some changes and works great.

```
namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

trait ModelTrait
{

    /**
     * Scopped Variables
     */
    protected $table_prefix              =  "prefix_";

    /**
     * Appends prefix to table name
     * 
     * @return $table
     */
    public function getTable() {

        $model                           =  explode("\\", get_class($this));
        $model                           =  Str::lower(array_pop($model));

        if (!isset($this->table)) $this->setTable(Str::plural($this->table_prefix . $model));

        return $this->table;

    }

}
```

Add a trait like this and in model use it like this:

```
class Model {
    use ModelTrait;
}
```